# Rails generate model with default parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a base model `MyAppRecordBase` which inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` and which all other models inherit from.  How do I set a default parent model for `rails generate model XYZ`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following in `environments/development.rb`

```
  config.generators.active_record[:parent] = 'MyAppRecordBase'
```

Alternatively you can set it on the command line with

```
rails generate model Dog --parent MyAppRecordBase
```